# Documenting not yet existing REST functions

Tags: java, json, rest, pdf

At the moment, in my company, we have tons of REST functions working and we will create more soon. We want to publish a documentation page for those API calls that doesn't exist yet. In that way, the UI guys can work even if we don't have have the real API yet.

I know for the existing ones, Swagger is ok but, for the ones that does not exist yet, we can not create "empty" methods and publish them just for Swagger to take them and show the documentation.

Also with Swagger I am not able to show multiple REAL payload examples for a particular request.

Doing some research, I found POSTMAN. Even if I don't have the real API yet, with POSTMAN I am able to document every element that I need. But.... POSTMAN does not have a "Pretty Print" functionality yet.

So I decided to export from POSTMAN a JSON file with all its content about my API calls, including sample payload requests. After that, I WANT to code a program in Java, receiving that json file and giving me the desired output in PDF or HTML format according to my selection when invoking my java program. (something like: java -jar Convert.jar sample.json pdf)

At the moment, I have successfully loaded (in my java program) the json file in memory and it is an actual complex big POJO object.

My question: Should I iterate over the object and its child objects (manually) in order to produce a generic HTML file with its information? Or does exist a generic library or function that receives a big POJO and presents that object in a generic (yet well presented) HTML (or pdf) format?

Thanks.